# SQL Server 2008 R2 Data Export Problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to export data from my production DB to my development DB but I am getting this error:

> Messages  Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the
>   read-only column "id".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Is there a way to check which column is that because I have 20 tables that all of them use the column name `id` or at least get a better error report?

Comment: I'm guessing it has more to do with permissions on any of your tables in your dev database than any one table in the 20 you are trying to import data into.  Are there any restrictions on the user id you're using in the dev database?

Comment: no I am the administrator so my username has access to complete any task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I had to do was:

- Right-click on the column (in this case 'ID')
- Select Modify
- Inside the Column Properties scroll down until you see Identity Specification
- Expand the view and select NO from the drop down menu.

If anyone knows a different (faster) way of doing this please share

Answer (score 43):

Just click on `Edit mappings` when you choose tables to import from and to.  and check on the `Enable identity insert` checkbox. And you should do that for each choosen table. Then you can complete your import. It was helped me in the same situation.

Answer (score 5):

If the column ID is an identity column, it's likely set up to generate automatically when a row is inserted, and is not able to be directly written to.

To preserve linking from the production environment to the test, use:

```
SET Identity_Insert <TableName> ON
```

To allow you to write identity values.

Comment: well all of my ID columns generate automatically their values. I have to run your command 20 times then I suppose?(once for each table)

Comment: If your IDs are global, you would only have to run it for the table that's responsible for generating the values.  The other tables are likely not specified as IDENTITY columns.

Comment: well on your example you have <TableName>. I tried it with one of my tables but it did not work. This is the error: 'Table 'users' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.'

Comment: Is the [users] table where the identities are coming from?  It would suggest that the [ID] column in the other tables represent user IDs.  A useful source of information is: sp_help [TableName]; This will give you information on the columns in the table, what you're looking for is the table that has an entry in the output detailing what if any identity column there is. Note: You want to do apply the setting in the test/target environment, not the production, as those are the identities you want to insert.

Comment: I just removed the auto generated function from the ID's and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as though you might be trying to insert values into a column that has been declared as an IDENTITY field.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is a bit late but I'm posting it anyway for the sake of providing to community.

I assume that you are trying to copy tables (not partial data). My answer is based on this assumption.

1. Connect to the source db via Object Explorer in SSMS.
2. **Right click the db** that you want its tables to be copied.
3. Go to **'Tasks' --> 'Export'**.
4. Choose your source and destination server and if you don't want additional script to be run before hands just press next ('Copy data from one or more tables or views'). Now you may select tables you want to be copied to the destination.

Select tables that you want to be completely copied to the destination. And click on 'edit mappings'. Here you may 'enable identity insert'. You will also have other options so check the screen before pressing OK.

If you do not use an express edition of SSMS here you may create an SSIS package to create jobs and to automatize this process in the future. You may check 'run immediately' and follow the screen about how it goes with all the warnings and errors. Hopefully you will get none. Good luck!

```
Tested with:
(
    Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86) 
    Jun 17 2011 00:57:23 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 <X86> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
)
```